# pygame.mixer.Sound only plays a popping noise and exits. Why?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to play sound using Python via pygame but all I hear is a popping noise and then the program quits. The length of the track is at least 20 seconds long but my program quits almost immediately after the pop.

I've tried solutions other than pygame and I hear popping on those as well. Just not sure why it just pops and quits and it seems like it's related to my machine (Mac).

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("SampleAudio_0.4mb.wav")
sound.play()
while pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    pygame.time.delay(1000000)
```

Comment: Maybe `pygame.mixer.get_busy()` returns `False`? Can you print this out before the `while` loop?

Comment: Can you step through your program to see where the actual fault is? And as @quamrana suggests when in doubt print it out.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses! I did a print pygame.mixer.get_busy() before and after sound.play() and it prints 0 and then 1 so that part is working.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this wav file: http://www.anzwad.com/dods/sound/ambient/thunder2.wav

I ran

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("thunder2.wav")
sound.play()
print(pygame.mixer.get_busy())
while pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    print(pygame.mixer.get_busy())
    pygame.time.delay(1000)
print(pygame.mixer.get_busy())
```

It printed this:

```
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
```

Does this work for you?
For me the 1's (the 1's mean that `get_busy` is returning true) are printed during the playing of the sound file then, right when the sound is complete and the delay finishes, the program closes.

Is that the functionality that you'd like?

**Note** my python version is 3.7.1

If this python code does not have the same functionality on your machine it may enable us to pinpoint the issue.

**If the sound file that you are using publicly available and you post a link, I can test my program with that file as well.**

Comment: Omg it worked! It looks like it has more to do with the file itself! Is there a good way to test if a specific music file is compatible with pygame?

Comment: @PeterYoon The docs: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html say any OGG or uncompressed wav should work. I am glad I at least clarified the location of the issue even if I couldn't solve it.